# Ngx-bootstrap datepicker custom ranges

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I would like to add some buttons with my custom ranges in datepicker. I'm using Quick select ranges from ngx-bootstrap: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#quick-select-ranges

I am able to use them, but in my case, I would like to ask, if there is a possibility to get an event from those buttons? I need exactly the event from those buttons, not from changing date directly by clicking on any button. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [api reference](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#api-reference) you can subscribe to the `bsValueChange` event emitter under the Outputs section.

> Emits when datepicker value has been changed

---

Here is an example of how to subscribe to the component api:

ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BsDaterangepickerDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-daterangepicker',
  templateUrl: './date-range-picker.component.html'
})
export class DateRangePickerComponent {
  ranges: any = [{
    value: [new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 7)), new Date()],
    label: 'Last 7 Days'
  }, {
    value: [new Date(), new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7))],
    label: 'Next 7 Days'
  }];

  @ViewChild(BsDaterangepickerDirective, { static: false }) dateRangePicker: BsDaterangepickerDirective;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dateRangePicker.bsValueChange.subscribe(res => console.log(res));    
  }
}
```

html:

```
<input type="text"            
       bsDaterangepicker
       [bsConfig]="{ ranges: ranges }">
```

Comment: In the below image, the first text box selected date is the start date for the second text box in daterangepicker. I am unable to set the initial date for the date range picker.https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T09NT2DD4-F01LD27LQUX/image.png

Comment: can't see the image